# What is the logical error for this Python program to generate all possible unique ways to represent n=3 as sum of positive integers?

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, recursive-backtracking

Python program to generate all possible unique ways to represent n=3 as sum of positive integers:

```
def fun():
    res=[]
    a=[]
    def backtracking(n):
        if(n==0):
            res.append(a)
            print(res)
            return
        if(n<0):
            return
        for i in range(1,n+1):
            a.append(i)
            backtracking(n-i)
            a.pop()
    backtracking(3)
    return res

print(fun())
```

Expecting `res = [[1,1,1][1,2][2,1][3]]` instead getting `[ [] [] [] [] ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending the list `a` directly to the `res`, you should be appending a copy of the list `a` instead. List is passed by reference, so in the end, your `res` has 4 references to the same list which is empty. To get a copy of the list you have different options - [`list.copy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) , [copy.copy()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) method, or just slicing `list[:]`

```
def fun():
    res=[]
    a=[]
    def backtracking(n):
        if(n==0):
            res.append(a.copy())  # updated
            # print(res)
            return
        if(n<0):
            return
        for i in range(1,n+1):
            a.append(i)
            backtracking(n-i)
            a.pop()
    backtracking(3)
    return res

print(fun())
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [3]]
```